# Shorten code: merge arrays from hashes

Tags: perl, refactoring, perl-data-structures, perl-hash

I have a list of hashes and some of the hashes contain a key which provides an array itself.

```
my @cars = (
   { # empty car
      name => "BMW",
   },
   { # car with passengers
      name => "Mercedes",
      passengers => [qw(Paul Willy)],
   },
   ...
)
```

It's pretty much like above but of course not with the stupid cars example:-)

Now I need to get a list of all "passengers" from all hashes including ones that do not even offer a passengers array.

In a 2nd step I need to retrieve unique entries from the list (actually the passengers are Perl object refs and I need every object once in the list)

At the moment I do:

```
my (@all, @passengers, %seen);
for(@cars) {
    push @all, @{$_->{passengers}} if $_->{passengers};
}

@passengers = grep { ! $seen{$_} ++ } @all;
```

I would like to get rid of @all and throw the list of all passengers directly into `grep`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another variation. It uses [`List::MoreUtils::uniq`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils#uniq). The `%seen` stuff is good to know, but unnecessary these days.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw<uniq>;

my @passengers 
    = sort uniq map { @$_ } grep { defined } map { $_->{passengers} } @cars
    ;
```

Of course, using my idiom of `list_if`, I would just do this:

```
 my @passengers = sort uniq map { list_if( $_->{passengers} ) } @cars;
```

Where `list_if` is defined as:

```
sub list_if {
    use Params::Util qw<_ARRAY _HASH>;

    return unless my $cond = shift;
    return unless my $ref
        = @_ == 0 ? $cond
        : @_ == 1 ? $_[0]
        :          \@_
        ;
    return !ref( $ref )   ? $ref
         : _ARRAY( $ref ) ? @$ref
         : _HASH( $ref )  ? %$ref
         :                  ()
         ;              
}
```

It's been a useful idiom for cutting down on long-hand approaches to deciding whether to "stream" array and hash refs or not.

Comment: I did now accept your answer just because it's the most readable one. Also note that for my scenario the `sort` call is not necessary. If I found the `list_if` on CPAN I would possibly use it:)

Comment: @halo, thanks for the encouragement. :) I have a bunch of idioms that help me do stuff I do a lot. Yeah, I know it didn't call for sort, I just put the sort in there so it's purty if you wanted to dump the list of passengers.

Answer (score 6):

```
my %seen;
my @passengers = grep { ! $seen{$_} ++ }
                 map { @{$_->{passengers} || []} } @cars;
```

Answer (score 2):

It bugs me to create an array and a reference only to immediately get rid of it both (like cjm did), so I'd use

```
my %seen;
my @passengers =
   grep !$seen{$_}++,
   map $_ ? @$_ : (),
   map $_->{passengers},
   @cars;
```

or

```
my %seen;
my @passengers =
   grep !$seen{$_}++,
   map @{ $_->{passengers} },
   grep $_->{passengers},
   @cars;
```

Comment: Nice solution, too. I find cjm's solution shorter and somewhat cleaner (which is a matter of taste in this case). Getting rid of the zero-length array is a nice thing. I'll do some benchmarks on that and possibly accept your solution. Although the difference in speed should be neglectable.

Comment: @halo, I agree with that speed should not be the deciding factor here.